# How to convert NURBS control points into 3D triangles?

Tags: javascript, three.js, 3d

THREE.js provides high-level 3D graphics, however it does not support 3D curves; it only supports a [2D SplineCurve](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/extras/curves/SplineCurve).

Luckly there is a [NURBS manipulator](https://github.com/standardcyborg/nurbs#open-b-spline) available at npmjs.com, supporting any dimension degree. I think what I need from nurbs is the method [`NURBS(controlPoints).evaluate()`](https://github.com/standardcyborg/nurbs#splineevaluateout-t0-t1--tn_1).

However I'm not understanding what arguments are expected to this `evaluate()` method. I want to convert NURBS control points into something THREE.js understands, such as triangles.

```
import NURBS from 'nurbs';

let curve = NURBS({
    points: [[-1, 0, 0], [-0.5, 0.5, 0.5], [0.5, -0.5, -0.5], [1, 0, 0]],
    degree: 3,
});

let r = [0, 0, 0];
curve.evaluate(r, 0, 0, 0);
console.log(r); // [ 4.083333333333332, -19.249999999999996, -19.249999999999996 ]
curve.evaluate(r, .1, .1, .1);
console.log(r); // [ 3.5756666666666677, -17.527, -17.527 ]
```

Comment: Have you seen this example? https://threejs.org/examples/?q=nurbs#webgl_geometry_nurbs

Comment: @prisoner849 It doesn't use the nurbs package (https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/dev/examples/webgl_geometry_nurbs.html) and [dev/examples/jsm/curves](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/tree/dev/examples/jsm/curves)), but that looks more easy. Thanks!